# VBA - Show Formula in cell when variable value

Tags: vba, formula

The code below shows only value in cell. How do I make it show the whole path from where it was taken?

```
If Worksheets("Final").Cells(j, 8).value = "Gross" Then
      Worksheets("Final").Cells(j, 11).value = .Cells(i, 2).value
      Worksheets("Final").Cells(j, 12).value = "=(" & .Cells(i, 2).value & ")"
End If
```

It shows the value only:

[image]
I would like it to show:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Worksheets("Final").Cells(j, 12).Formula = "='" & .Name & "'!" & .Cells(i, 2).Address(False, False)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but it still shows only the value.

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay attention to the "dot" before "Cells(i,2) ". See edited code

Comment: @MrNoNo, is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, it is working! I just had to add "." before "Address". Thanks a lot!